# wallpaper as background of start menu in lxde

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, desktop-background

When you click on start menu, there is a main menu pop up. I like to hide the background on it covered with wallpaper.

Comment: I have Lubuntu. nope, this question is completely different.

Comment: Well, I want to make menu background 100 percent transparent with icon and menus completely visible (well, this is not transparency, it is simply show and hide, sorry for confusion). same type of setting exist for panel (panel preferences-> background -> solid color-> set transparent color(#000000) and background of panel shows desktop)

Comment: I modified the question to make it more clear